# MoodleXML Cloze parser

Tags: python, xml, parsing, moodle

I am trying to parse Moodle Embedded Question (cloze) question type

But I have problems splitting multiple cloze questions

My input looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<quiz>
  <question type="category">
    <category>
      <text>$course$/top/Default for my course</text>
    </category>
    <info format="moodle_auto_format">
      <text>The default category for questions shared in context 'my course'.</text>
    </info>
    <idnumber></idnumber>
  </question>
<!-- question: 178460  -->
  <question type="cloze">
    <name>
      <text>Vprašanje 2</text>
    </name>
    <questiontext format="html">
      <text><![CDATA[
      
<p>V knjižnici imajo <b>9</b> kopij knjige iz verjetnosti in statistike,
    pri čemer so kopije oštevilčene.</p>

    <p> V ponedeljek si knjigo izposodi <b>5</b> študentov.  Na koliko
    načinov si lahko študentje izposodije knjige, pri čemer je pomembno, katero
    kopijo knjige ima posamezni študent?&nbsp; {1:NUMERICAL:=15120:0.0001#Pravilno!} Na koliko načinov lahko
    kopije knjige ostanejo v knjižnici (kopije so oštevilčene)?&nbsp; {1:NUMERICAL:=126:0.0001#Pravilno!}
    </p>
    
    <p>Čez en mesec knjige vrne v knjižnico <b>4</b> študentov. Knjižničarka
    knjige zloži na police, pri čemer izbira med 3 policami. Na koliko načinov
    lahko razporedi knjige na police?
    Police med seboj razlikujemo, vrstni red knjig na polici pa ni
    pomemben.&nbsp; {1:NUMERICAL:=81:0.0001#Pravilno!} </p>

    <p>Štirinajst dni pred izpitom se teh <b>4</b> študentov odloči obnoviti
    svoje znanje in se med prostima urama ponovno odpravijo v knjižnico. Vsak
    izbere svojo knjigo in se
    usede za okroglo mizo z <b>9</b> stoli. Na koliko načinov se lahko
    usedejo za mizo, pri čemer razporeditvi štejemo za enaki, če lahko iz ene
    pridemo v drugo tako, da se vsi študenti presedejo
    za isto število štolov v isto smer?&nbsp; {1:NUMERICAL:=336:0.0001#Pravilno!} </p>
      
      ]]>
      </text>
    </questiontext>
    <generalfeedback format="html">
      <text></text>
    </generalfeedback>
    <penalty>0.3333333</penalty>
    <hidden>0</hidden>
    <idnumber></idnumber>
  </question>
</quiz>
```

So for simplicity lets focus on the  part (since the rest of the parser is working fine)

```
<p>V knjižnici imajo <b>9</b> kopij knjige iz verjetnosti in statistike,
    pri čemer so kopije oštevilčene.</p>

    <p> V ponedeljek si knjigo izposodi <b>5</b> študentov.  Na koliko
    načinov si lahko študentje izposodije knjige, pri čemer je pomembno, katero
    kopijo knjige ima posamezni študent?&nbsp; {1:NUMERICAL:=15120:0.0001#Pravilno!} Na koliko načinov lahko
    kopije knjige ostanejo v knjižnici (kopije so oštevilčene)?&nbsp; {1:NUMERICAL:=126:0.0001#Pravilno!}
    </p>
```

As you can see the first question doesn't have an anwser, but thats fine (it should be like that)

Now here is my parser for this question type

```
import re
class EmbeddedAnswer:
    def __init__(self, answer_str):
        if answer_str is None:
            self.gap = None
            self.answer_type = None
            self.solution = None
            self.tolerance = None
            self.feedback = None
        else:
            parts = answer_str.split(':')
            self.gap = int(parts[0][1:])
            self.answer_type = parts[1]
            if self.answer_type == "NM":
                self.solution = float(parts[2][1:])
                self.tolerance = float(parts[3].split('#')[0].strip('}'))
                self.feedback = None
            else:
                self.solution = parts[2][1:]
                self.tolerance = float(parts[3].split('#')[0].strip('}'))
                self.feedback = parts[3].split('#')[1].strip('}')
        
    def get_gap(self):
        return self.gap
    
    def get_answer_type(self):
        return self.answer_type
    
    def get_solution(self):
        return self.solution
    
    def get_tolerance(self):
        return self.tolerance
    
    def get_feedback(self):
        return self.feedback
        
class QA:
    def __init__(self, question, answer):
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer

qa_list = []

text = """
<p>V knjižnici imajo <b>9</b> kopij knjige iz verjetnosti in statistike,
    pri čemer so kopije oštevilčene.</p>

    <p> V ponedeljek si knjigo izposodi <b>5</b> študentov.  Na koliko
    načinov si lahko študentje izposodije knjige, pri čemer je pomembno, katero
    kopijo knjige ima posamezni študent?&nbsp; {1:NUMERICAL:=15120:0.0001#Pravilno!} Na koliko načinov lahko
    kopije knjige ostanejo v knjižnici (kopije so oštevilčene)?&nbsp; {1:NUMERICAL:=126:0.0001#Pravilno!}
    </p>
"""

# split the text by <p> tags
p_list = re.split('<p>|</p>|<br>|<br />', text)

# remove any empty strings from the list
p_list = [p.strip() for p in p_list if p.strip()]

# iterate over the list and create instances of the QA class
for i in range(0, len(p_list)):
    question = p_list[i]
    #question can also include 2 questions inside of it
    #question = re.split(r'(?<=\})\s+', question)
    question = re.split(r'(?<=\})\s+(?=<br />)', question)
    answer = None
    
    if len(question) > 1:
        for j in range(0, len(question)):
                match = re.search(r'{.*?}', question[j])
                if match:
                    answer = match.group(0)
                    question[j] = question[j].replace(answer, '')
                qa_list.append(QA(question[j], EmbeddedAnswer(answer)))
    else:
        match = re.search(r'{.*?}', p_list[i])
        if match:
            answer = match.group(0)
            question[0] = question[0].replace(answer, '')
        qa_list.append(QA(question[0], EmbeddedAnswer(answer)))
    
# print out the questions and answers in the list
qa = qa_list[1]
print(qa.question + "|" + str(qa.answer.get_solution()))
```

Unfortionatly the second question

```
    <p> V ponedeljek si knjigo izposodi <b>5</b> študentov.  Na koliko
    načinov si lahko študentje izposodije knjige, pri čemer je pomembno, katero
    kopijo knjige ima posamezni študent?&nbsp; {1:NUMERICAL:=15120:0.0001#Pravilno!} Na koliko načinov lahko
    kopije knjige ostanejo v knjižnici (kopije so oštevilčene)?&nbsp; {1:NUMERICAL:=126:0.0001#Pravilno!}
    </p>
```

Has 2 questions in it, but my parser treats this like one question
So When I want to get the second question qa_list[1].question

Instead of geting this out

```
V ponedeljek si knjigo izposodi <b>5</b> študentov.  Na koliko
    načinov si lahko študentje izposodije knjige, pri čemer je pomembno, katero
    kopijo knjige ima posamezni študent?
```

I get this out

```
V ponedeljek si knjigo izposodi <b>5</b> študentov.  Na koliko
    načinov si lahko študentje izposodije knjige, pri čemer je pomembno, katero
    kopijo knjige ima posamezni študent?&nbsp;  Na koliko načinov lahko
    kopije knjige ostanejo v knjižnici (kopije so oštevilčene)?&nbsp; {1:NUMERICAL:=126:0.0001#Pravilno!}
```

So to clarify one question has 2 questions inside, but my parser treats this like one question

Hopefully someone can tell me what the problem is

Thanks for ANwsering and Best Regards